# CouchDB : permission of databases moved from remote machines

Tags: ubuntu, couchdb

I moved .couch files (e.g., test.couch) to `/var/lib/couchdb/1.0.1` from the remote ubuntu machine. 
Then, I tried to get the database information stored in test.couch via the following command.

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:5984/test
```

However, I received the error.

```
{"error":"kill","reason":"{gen_server,call,\n    [couch_server,\n     {open,<<\"test\">>,\n         [{user_ctx,\n              {user_ctx,null,\n                  [<<\"_admin\">>],\n                 <<\"{couch_httpd_auth, default_authentication_handler}\">>}}]},\n     infinity]}"}
```

The owner and group of all the .couch files are `couchdb`. 
The databases (e.g., _users.couch) made on the local work.

I already looked the following articles, but cannot solve the problem.

[Migrate couchdb data from 0.10.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364430/migrate-couchdb-data-from-0-10-0)

[Staging setup with couchdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835918/staging-setup-with-couchdb)

The machine is ubuntu 12.04.5.

How can I open .couch files moved from other machines?

Comment: Did you follow the advice in the answer? About trying to replicate it and seeing it if works and checking the logs.